# Insert in a file without overwriting without using a 2nd file using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, file, text

The below are the contents in a text file.

> name1: 1234
>    name2: 2000
>   name3: 3000

This is an existing text file and I want to replace one value(say 1234) with another value (say 12345) in the text file. so I placed the cursor at start of the value (here its the 7th position) . Then i used the following statement:

> fprintf(filepointer,"12345\n");

The resultant file is like

> name1: 12345
>   ame2 : 2000
>   name3 : 3000

Its overwriting the 4 characters("1000") and a newline('\n') and 'n' with 5 characters("12345") and a newline('\n').

The solutions I know are:
1. Overwriting the entire file to add one extra character.
2. Copying each line in a linked list node and change the characters in the memory  and write in the same file.
3. Create a temp file and copy the new characters to the desired place in the temp file and change the name of the temp file to source file name and delete the source file.

Also I tried adding carriage return '\r' and windows format of EOF ('\r\n') , still the next line characters are overwritten. Also I expanded the file size using [SetEndOfFile][1] API and still I face the same problem. I searched many forums and found answers like "It is not possible to insert characters without overwriting".

Is there any solution just to insert characters without overwriting the characters in the middle of the file. or any logic to insert characters in a line and not affect the next line.
Thanks in advance.

Is it possible Using visual studio VC++ ??
Thanks:)

Comment: Just FYI, `C/C++` is UB. :)

Comment: Without using a more structured file format, this is very cumbersome (i.e. impractical).  How about using sqlite?

Comment: You can replace 1234 with say 6789 - note these string are the same length.  However what you are trying to do is insert (your new string is 1 character longer) into the middle of a file, this is not possible. You need to use one of the solutions you outlined above.

Comment: Yeah.. it's usual to use a temp file, ie, (3).  Why?  It's easier to recover from that mechanism if it gets interrupted by a crash.

Comment: You can't, unless the replacement is exactly the same length as the replaced text. Otherwise you need to copy the file.

Comment: This is done differently in C and C++. Make up your mind about the programming language.

Comment: @Lundin Any of these two programming language is fine by me. Thanks:)

Comment: @ejp i'm afraid you're are wrong. You can replace 1234 with 123 and vice versa if you use : 'fprintf(filepointer,"%s\r",array);'. The 'array[]' should contain only 3 or 4 characters followed with '\0'.

Comment: @trojanfoe Can you suggest any open source library. Thanks:)

Comment: @Giriprakash no, not in general.  It depends on how the file is parsed later. An extra nul char may be interpreted as an empty field rather than a non-existent field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequential file is ehh... just *sequential*. All the bytes follow each other with no notion of line or any other structure.

The only operations allowed by the underlying file system are (only speaking of writing):

- **replace** bytes anywhere in the file
- add bytes **at the end** of the file
- truncate the file (or add random(*) bytes at the end by moving the end of file

There is no provision for *insertion in the middle* so no language will be able to do that (except by doing overwriting under the hood)

(*) if you move the end of file forward more than one logical block (file system sense) many file systems will create a hole that is a *phantom* block that does not use any space on disk and is read as null bytes

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any solution just to insert characters without overwriting
>   the characters in the middle of the file. or any logic to insert
>   characters in a line and not affect the next line.

No, what you ask for is not possible with any file system I've ever used.

Use method (3), a temp file.  Use a temp file with a different, unique extension added/replaced, eg '.tmp', so that the temp files can be recognised on startup, then:

1) Get source file name, eg. 'source.txt'

2) Append, or replace a    '.tmp' extension: 'source.txt.tmp'

3) Open the two files

4) Read the   source, modify, write the temp

5) Close both

6) Delete source file

7)  rename temp file

When you program starts:

1) search for files with '.tmp' extension.

2) if found, eg.    'source.txt.tmp', take the file name and remove the extension, eg    'source.txt'

3) Test if a file with that name exists

4) If so, delete  the temp file

5) If not, rename the temp file

Result: if the process crashes, you end up with either an intact, unmodified source file, or an intact, modified source file.

Comment: [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) will rename the temp file and implicitly delete the old file in an atomic operation, so you're never left in the situation where you have to decide what to do - the original file will always exist.